# class name that control gray part of jquery modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

When we raise a jquery modal dialog, another part of page will become gray. I want to know what is the class name of the gray part? I want to control this part, so how can I write this selector?

Answer (score 2):

In a modal dialog the css class of the modal gray layer has the class

```
ui-widget-overlay
```

The default CSS rule for the ui-widget-overlay is

```
    .ui-widget-overlay {
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         background: #aaaaaa url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
         opacity: .3;
         filter: Alpha(Opacity=30);
    }
```

Of course this rule is different from theme to theme.